# Does the process of photosynthesis occur in insectivorous plants?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis, growth, environment, habitat

Does the process of photosynthesis occur in insectivorous plants? 
Can you please give me a clear answer and explain to me how?
and also can you describe the environment in which they grow ?
Thank you

Comment: is this a homework question? you need to give a little more detail and effort when posting to this site... please see the help page where it discusses "how to ask a good question" - thanks!

Comment: Normally the carnivorous plants are photosynthetic and green. They need to depend on animals for nitrogen. They are adapted to regions of poor nitrogen availability in soil.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused  if you know the answer then post it as an answer. Use comments only to request clarification and suggesting something.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Ok but before that I'll have to go through some reference. However I've seen possible-answers, or where could be looked for, sometimes posted (and they helps, too). As well for unconfirmed answers sometimes it is told that "post it as a comment instead".

Answer (score 1):

"Carnivorous plants are plants that derive some or most of their nutrients (but not energy) from trapping and consuming animals or protozoans, typically insects and other arthropods. Carnivorous plants have adapted to grow in places with high light where the soil is thin or poor in nutrients, especially nitrogen, such as acidic bogs and rock outcroppings."

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivorous_plant